# Doctype issue for active link

Tags: html, css

The CSS active link property is not working in ASP.net.
When i comment the Doctype, it starts working fine. Following is the Doctype:

```
 <DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

I found many doctypes but the other CSS stops working when I change.
Is there any way to use active link property with this doctype?

This is the HTML and CSS code

```
 <DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
a:active
{
    background-color:Red;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#">w3schools.com</a>
<a href="#">wikipedia.org</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using that specific doctype? Do you have a special reason for using it?

Comment: When i change this doctype the css in my all application stop working. Can you suggest me any other Doctype?

Comment: I think the consensus is that the HTML 5 doctype is ready for use: [What's the best doctype?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1570104) even if the HTML  you use is HTML 4

Comment: Did you test this exact document on some browser(s)? Which browsers? Which other doctype produced different results? As you have tagged this as an asp.net question but do not describe anything asp.net related, this is probably a misinterpretation of a quite different problem.
Your code has an error, since the doctype declaration lacks an exclamation mark “!” before “DOCTYPE”, so the page is shown in quirks mode. But using doctypes that trigger “standards mode” does not affect the styling of active links.

Comment: @Jukkak.korpela if you dont know answer of any question then why you start commenting about that? This is default doctype of asp.net web application ok other thing is i'am working in asp.net. So please dont try to waste other persons time ok...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the HTML 5 doctype, `<!doctype html>`.

If you choose to stick with the one you're currently using, do it this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Please notice the `!` at the beginning. You need those. :)